# Missing columns names when using sapply to pass a function

Tags: r, sapply, desctools

I am trying to loop over the columns in a dataframe to get descriptives. Since some columns throw errors, I wanted to use `tryCatch` function to ignore the error & continue. For this purpose I use `sapply` and pass the formula.In this process, I lose the names of the columns. How do I get them? Thank you in advance.

```
    data(mtcars)
    names(mtcars)
    library(DescTools)
    wrd<-GetNewWrd()
    sapply(mtcars, function(fnm){tryCatch(Desc(fnm, plotit=TRUE, wrd=wrd),error=function(e) NULL)})
```

Comment: That is a feature or lapply and sapply. Instead pass the names and pull from the object.

Comment: Desc should normally handle errors and keep the process going on. Can you specify the mentioned error in more detail?